# Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given

Tags: php, warnings, elementor

Hello to all dear masters
I am developing a WordPress template and I continued to install the elementor plugin and proceeded according to the site description, but this warning appears to me when editing the product.

> Warning: foreach () argument must be of type array | object, null given in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ panda.com \ wp-content \ plugins \ elementor \ includes \ base \ element-base.php on line 138

And this is the code that gives this error

```php
foreach ($this->get_script_depends() as $script) {

    if (isset($deprecated_scripts[$script])) {
        Utils::handle_deprecation($script, $deprecated_scripts[$script]['version'], $deprecated_scripts[$script]['replacement']);
    }

    wp_enqueue_script($script);
}
```

Thanks for guiding me

Comment: it seeems that your **$this-> get_script_depends()** is returning a null value or an empty string. Ensure that it does not return any null or empty string value.

Comment: `$ this->` INVALID SYNTAX. Remove the space between the `$` and the `this`

Comment: This space is created here, otherwise it is inside the file without space

Comment: The formatter here does not create spaces on code

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, this space must have been created when I typed, but this space does not exist in the template file

Comment: @RajuAhmed How can I fix it?

Comment: $ this-> get_script_depends () is `NULL`, var_dump and you will see that's `NULL`